# Can't Access Static Drop-down Inside an Iframe

Tags: iframe, drop-down-menu, static, cypress

I want to click on a dropdown inside an iframe and select some options, but i keep getting this error in cypress

**cypress-iframe commands can only be applied to exactly one iframe at a time.  Instead found 2**

**Please see my code below**
`

```
it('Publish and Lock Results', function(){
         setClasses.clickTools()
         setClasses.clickConfiguration()
         setClasses.publishAndLockResult()
 
         cy.frameLoaded();
         cy.wait(5000)
         cy.iframe().find("body > div:nth-child(6) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > form:nth-child(2) > table:nth-child(5) > tbody:nth-child(1) > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(5) > p:nth-child(2)").click()
         
  })
```

````
```**Please see screenshot of the element** 
[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpUfn.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpUfn.png)
````

Answer (score 0):

There should be an iframe identifier that you can use (anything else for the iframe, a unique id, class or attribute, like `data-test`)

```js
let iframe = cy.get(iframeIdentifier).its('0.contentDocument.body').should('not.be.empty').then(cy.wrap)

iframe.find("body > div:nth-child(6) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > form:nth-child(2) > table:nth-child(5) > tbody:nth-child(1) > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(5) > p:nth-child(2)").click()
```

From what the output is suggesting, you've got two iframes on that page that it's trying to send commands to, and you have to pick one

Answer adapted from source: [cypress.io blog post on working with iframes](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2020/02/12/working-with-iframes-in-cypress/)